# Tooltip on the postion where i hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

i have used [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-better-tooltip-with-jquery-awesomeness/) tooltip in my project its working great but the problem is that i need the tooltip  appear where ever i hover and not fixed location.currently its appearing in fixed location.i need to appear the tooltip where i hover.

how can i retouch this code to do so

```
  /* Position the tooltip relative to the class 
       associated with the tooltip                */  
    setTip = function(top, left){  
        var topOffset = tip.height();  
        var xTip = (left-30)+"px";  
        var yTip = (top-topOffset-60)+"px";  
        tip.css({'top' : yTip, 'left' : xTip});  
    }
```

the full code is here

```
  $.fn.betterTooltip = function(options){

/* Setup the options for the tooltip that can be 
   accessed from outside the plugin              */
var defaults = {
    speed: 200,
    delay: 300
};

var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

/* Create a function that builds the tooltip 
   markup. Then, prepend the tooltip to the body */
getTip = function() {
    var tTip = 
        "<div class='tip'>" +
            "<div class='tipMid'>"  +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='tipBtm'></div>" +
        "</div>";
    return tTip;
}
$("body").prepend(getTip());

/* Give each item with the class associated with 
   the plugin the ability to call the tooltip    */
$(this).each(function(){

    var $this = $(this);
    var tip = $('.tip');
    var tipInner = $('.tip .tipMid');

    var tTitle = (this.title);
    this.title = "";

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var tLeft = offset.left;
    var tTop = offset.top;
    var tWidth = $this.width();
    var tHeight = $this.height();

    /* Mouse over and out functions*/
    $this.hover(
        function() {
            tipInner.html(tTitle);
            setTip(tTop, tLeft);
            setTimer();
        }, 
        function() {
            stopTimer();
            tip.hide();
        }
    );         

    /* Delay the fade-in animation of the tooltip */
    setTimer = function() {
        $this.showTipTimer = setInterval("showTip()", defaults.delay);
    }

    stopTimer = function() {
        clearInterval($this.showTipTimer);
    }

    /* Position the tooltip relative to the class 
       associated with the tooltip                */
    setTip = function(top, left){
        var topOffset = tip.height();
        var xTip = (left-30)+"px";
        var yTip = (top-topOffset-60)+"px";
        tip.css({'top' : yTip, 'left' : xTip});
    }

    /* This function stops the timer and creates the
       fade-in animation                          */
    showTip = function(){
        stopTimer();
        tip.animate({"top": "+=20px", "opacity": "toggle"}, defaults.speed);
    }
});
    };
```

Comment: I believe @Hidde's answer below solves your issue, but I would suggest using a well tested plugin that deals with loads of scenarios rather than reinventing the wheel! One I would suggest is http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ but there's more out there. I wouldn't discourage to use the above as a learning experience, but otherwise, I'd stick with well tested code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)** is short for **.mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut)**.  That means you have access to the mouse coords of the mousenter().

Change your .hover binding to use mouse coordinates of hover entry point:

```
/* Mouse over and out functions*/
$this.hover(
    function(e) {
        tipInner.html(tTitle);
        setTip(e.clientY, e.clientX);  //<--- using mouseenter coords here
        setTimer();
    }, 
    function() {
        stopTimer();
        tip.hide();
    }
).mousemove (function(e) {
    setTip(e.pageY, e.pageX);
});
```

Comment: i replace my code with ur code its changing the position but tooltip appear some where else that is above far from where i hover.

Comment: hmm..how far?  the tool tip should appear where you mouse enters the div, +/- the position adjustments you make to it in the setTip function.  I'll update the snippet to let your tooltip track the mouse movements above.

Answer (score 2):

Give it mouse coordinates instead of static div coordinates:

```
$(document).mousemove (function(e) {
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
});
```

jQuery docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: You don't put it anywhere, you USE it. Think about what it does, and how you can use that to provide the functionality you need. We are not here to write your code, we are here to help people. You have to solve your own problems though.